# Changes in Django View Lagging

Tags: python, django

I'm a fairly new to web development so this might actually be normal behavior - but when I make logic changes in my views, it can take about an hour for those changes to show up on my production site.

The changes are instant if I fire up the localhost. Server is Windows IIS 7.5. HTML, CSS, and JS changes show up instantly, it's the code in the view that takes a while to filter through. Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your deployed infrastructure -- how is it pulling in code changes? How does it know when to reload? Unfortunately we won't be able to answer this here without knowing more about your server configuration, and at that point it might be a better candidate for ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a manual reboot of the application pool where the site is sitting in IIS?  Documentation might not be exact for the version but it should explain it well enough to give you an idea about what's going:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx

Basically, if you have the application pool recycle every 3 hours, when you make a change it could take up to 3 hours for the change to take effect.  You also don't want it recycling every 5 minutes either.  But you can do a manual recycle if you really want to see your changes.